# how to pass variables from one function and use it in another function in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this code:

```
list1= [1,2,3,4]


def get_list():
    for i in list1:
        return i


def function_1():
    print(i + int(3))


function_1()
```

I try to pass the variable to another function and use it!

I get this error:

```
NameError: name 'i' is not defined
```

any idea( I dont want to use global)

Maybe this one is a better example:

```
def func1():
  a=8
  b=9
  return a,b

def func2():
  z=a+b
  return z 

print(z)
```

Comment: If you were to _call_ `get_list()`, then you could assign its return value to a variable so you might make use of it.

Comment: Still not able to get the variables

Comment: What output you want according to your code?

Comment: I want to pass the variable from get_list. and use it in the function_1. lets say def function_1(): print(i)

Comment: how can you then pass the variables of an function to another

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
print(map(lambda i: i + 3, list1))
```

Sometimes if you just want to change the data in a list just use map().

Comment: Thanks for you answer but I want to learn how to pass variables

Comment: If you use the return() function the program will not execute the function and instead, skip it to the next line of code.

Answer (score -1):

```
In [52]: list1= [1,2,3,4]
    ...: 
    ...: 
    ...: def get_list():
    ...:     for i in list1:
    ...:         function_1(i)
    ...: 
    ...: 
    ...: def function_1(i):
    ...:     print(i + int(3))
    ...: 
    ...: 
    ...: get_list()
```

Comment: Add some comments or explain it perhaps?